# Transform a List of One Type To Another

Tags: kotlin, transform

I have a list of type `A`. I want to turn it into a list of type `B`.

```
fun publish(listOne: List<A>) {
    val result: List<B> = 
}
```

Class `B` looks like this. It has a constructor that if you pass `A` then it will copy the variables and make a new instance of `B`.

```
class B(name: String ....) {

    constructor(a: A) {
       // copies the values of a then creates an instance.
    }
}
```

How can I use this constructor to make a new list of type `B`? Normally I would traverse the entire list of and make a new instance of `B` per instance of `A`. However, is there a way to do this in Kotlin that is easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just map the given list:

```
val result: List<B> = listOne.map(::B)
// or
val result: List<B> = listOne.map { B(it) }
```